# Tomcat command to check configuration files?

Tags: tomcat, command, tomcat7

One time I used a command on my Windows cmd to check, whether the configuration files of a Tomcat 7 are okay (or not).

Unfortunately I forgot about it and am therefore asking, whether someone can help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat currently has no such facility, and unfortunately due to the ability to use XML-based configuration for unknown components (for example, JDBC drivers), there isn't even an XML schema that can be used for validation.

The best you can do would be to either check the XML file(s) for well-formedness or actually launch Tomcat.

This seems like a good request for enhancement over at [ASF's Bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=Tomcat%208).

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately this is not true. I learned such a command in a Tomcat training and used it in the past too; unfortunately I forgot it.

Comment: I'd be happy to see such a command. There certainly doesn't exist such a command in the standard Tomcat distribution.

Comment: Will let you know, if I come across it again.